# unixODBC failed to connect can't open lib - libsqora.so' : file not found

Tags: oracle, aix, unixodbc

I am trying to configure unixODBC in AIX server. But I am getting error message that driver manager can't open lib: file not found.

Oracle client is installed in the server and sqlpus works without any issues in the same server.

Oracle Version: 12c (12.2)
UnixODBC: 2.3.7

I edited odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini appropriately and I have set the env variables: ORACLE_HOME, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PATH, TNS_ADMIN etc.

When I try to execute isql getting the below error:

```
 **bash-4.4$ isql -v ORCL**
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/XXXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libsqora.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

I did ldd as I could see in lot of blogs and in internet:

```
**bash-4.4$ ldd /XXXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libsqora.so**
/XXXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libsqora.so needs:
         /usr/lib/libodbcinst.a(libodbcinst.so.2)
ar: 0707-109 Member name libodbcinst.so.2 does not exist.
dump: /tmp/tmpdir19988686/extract/libodbcinst.so.2: 0654-106 Cannot open the specified file.
         /XXXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libclntsh.so
         /XXXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libclntshcore.so
         /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/librtl.a(shr.o)
         /unix
         /usr/lib/libperfstat.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5.o)
         /usr/lib/libc.a(aio.o)
         /usr/lib/libdl.a(shr.o)
         /XXXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libons.so
         /usr/lib/libodm.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libcfg.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/liblvm.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libcorcfg.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_comm.o)
         /usr/lib/libsrc.a(shr.o)
```

I am stuck here, any ideas on how to crack and make it work?

```
bash-4.4$ ar tv /usr/lib/libodbcinst.a
rwxr-xr-x   205/1     316902 Feb 07 13:36 2018 libodbcinst.so
```

Fresh installation in a new AIX server throws same error:

```
bash-4.4$ isql -v ORCL
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/XXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libsqora.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

But Ldd looks Ok:

```
bash-4.4$ ldd /XXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libsqora.so
/XXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libsqora.so needs:
        /opt/freeware/lib/libodbcinst.a(libodbcinst.so.2)
         /XXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libclntsh.so
         /XXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libclntshcore.so
         /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/librtl.a(shr.o)
         /unix
         /opt/freeware/lib/libltdl.so
         /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5.o)
         /usr/lib/libperfstat.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5.o)
         /usr/lib/libc.a(aio.o)
         /usr/lib/libdl.a(shr.o)
         /XXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libons.so
         /usr/lib/libodm.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr.o)
         /opt/freeware/lib/libgcc_s.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_comm.o)
         /usr/lib/libcfg.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/liblvm.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libcorcfg.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libsrc.a(shr.o)


bash-4.4$ ar tv /opt/freeware/lib/libodbcinst.a
rwxr-xr-x   205/1     316902 Feb 07 13:36 2018 libodbcinst.so
rwxr-xr-x   209/1     316902 Aug 28 11:14 2019 libodbcinst.so.2

bash-4.4$ ls /opt/freeware/lib/
gcc                       libfreebl3.a              libgthread-2.0.a          libncurses++.so           libodbc.so.2.0.0          libpopt.so.0              libsoftokn3.a
gettext                   libfreebl3.so             libgthread-2.0.so         libncurses++.so.6         libodbccr.a               libpopt.so.0.0.0          libsoftokn3.so
libatomic.a               libgcc_s.a                libgthread-2.0.so.0       libncurses++.so.6.1.0     libodbccr.so              libpython2.7.a            libsqlite3.a
libbz2.a                  libgdbm.a                 libhistory.a              libncurses.a              libodbccr.so.2            libpython2.7.so           libsqlite3.so
libcharset.a              libgettextlib-0.19.8.1.a  libhistory.so.6           libncurses.so             libodbccr.so.2.0.0        libreadline.a             libssl3.a
libcharset.la             libgettextlib.a           libiconv.a                libncurses.so.6           libodbcinst.a             libreadline.so.6          libssl3.so
libdb-4.8.a               libgettextsrc-0.19.8.1.a  libiconv.la               libncurses.so.6.1.0       libodbcinst.a.bak         librpm.so                 libstdc++.a
libdb-4.8.so              libgettextsrc.a           libintl.a                 libnspr4.a                libodbcinst.so            librpm.so.7               libz.a
libdb-4.a                 libgio-2.0.a              libltdl.a                 libnspr4.so               libodbcinst.so.2          librpm.so.7.0.1           pthread
libdb-4.so                libgio-2.0.so             libltdl.so                libnss3.a                 libodbcinst.so.2.0.0      librpmbuild.so            python2.7
libdb.a                   libgio-2.0.so.0           libltdl.so.7              libnss3.so                libpanel.a                librpmbuild.so.7          rpm
libdb.so                  libglib-2.0.a             libltdl.so.7.3.1          libnssckbi.a              libpanel.so               librpmbuild.so.7.0.1      rpm40
libdb4.a                  libglib-2.0.so            liblua-5.1.so             libnssckbi.so             libpanel.so.6             librpmio.so               rpmpopt
libexpat.a                libglib-2.0.so.0          liblua.a                  libnssdbm3.a              libpanel.so.6.1.0         librpmio.so.7             rpmrc
libffi.a                  libgmodule-2.0.a          libmagic.a                libnssdbm3.so             libplc4.a                 librpmio.so.7.0.1         terminfo
libffi.so.6               libgmodule-2.0.so         libmenu.a                 libnssutil3.a             libplc4.so                librpmsign.so
libform.a                 libgmodule-2.0.so.0       libmenu.so                libnssutil3.so            libplds4.a                librpmsign.so.7
libform.so                libgobject-2.0.a          libmenu.so.6              libodbc.a                 libplds4.so               librpmsign.so.7.0.1
libform.so.6              libgobject-2.0.so         libmenu.so.6.1.0          libodbc.so                libpopt.a                 libsmime3.a
libform.so.6.1.0          libgobject-2.0.so.0       libncurses++.a            libodbc.so.2              libpopt.so                libsmime3.so
```

Comment: Please edit your Original Post and quote the output of command `ar tv /usr/lib/libodbcinst.a`

Comment: The name of the of the archive-member is problematic. Create a backup, and try something like this: `cd /tmp; ar x /usr/lib/libodbcinst.a libodbcinst.so; mv libodbcinst.so libodbcinst.so.2; ar rcs /usr/lib/libodbcinst.a libodbcinst.so.2`

Comment: Wow! @LorinczyZsigmond, I was struggling for this for more than two weeks to get this sorted out. This solved my problem. Thanks you so much! Felt relieved. Your reply was really helpful, really appreciated :)

Comment: exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program ../bin32/aix/FKRUN because of the following errors:
0509-150 Dependent module /usr/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2) could not be loaded.
0509-152 Member libiconv.so.2 is not found in archive ....unfortunately another program which is using unixodbc throws the above error...any comments on this ? @LorinczyZsigmond

Comment: bash-4.4$ ar tv /usr/lib/libiconv.a
r--r--r-- 2/2 237843 Apr 10 20:11 2018 shr4.o
r--r--r-- 2/2 237965 Apr 10 20:11 2018 shr.o

Comment: Sadly, there is two `libiconv.a` in your system: `/usr/lib/libiconv.a` and `/opt/freeware/lib/libiconv.a`. You need the latter, you can use `LIBPATH` run-time or `-blibpath` linkage-time. Mind you, there is a catch: `/opt/freeware/lib/libiconv.a` should contain every elements of `/usr/lib/libiconv.a` (most likely it already settled). Explanation is here: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0009

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I remove /opt/freeware/lib/ then we would have only one libiconv.a inside usr/lib/ will it work? . Is it safe to do it ? @LorinczyZsigmond

Comment: Not at all. Instead, set `LIBPATH=/opt/freeware/lib` before executing the program.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Now above error has gone and new error is cropping up. I guess there is a conflict btw both the libs. Any suggestions ?.....following errors:
0509-022 Cannot load module /opt/freeware/lib/libltdl.so.
0509-150 Dependent module libgcc_s.a(shr.o) could not be loaded.
0509-022 Cannot load module libgcc_s.a(shr.o).
0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
0509-022 Cannot load module FFFDIOC.
0509-150 Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libltdl.so could not be loaded.
0509-022 Cannot load module .

Comment: A simple way to get `/opt/lib/libgcc_s.a` is installing rpm-package `libgcc`. Eg. from here: http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Gcc

Comment: Thanks @LorinczyZsigmond I will try and will post my results shortly.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Tried with fresh new installation, again I got the same error as shared in my initial post, but now ldd output looks ok. Updating my initial post with outputs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your Original Post and quote the output of command `ar tv /opt/freeware/lib/libodbcinst.a`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Updated my post

Comment: From this link: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0041 build `dltest32` and examine the output of command `./dltest32 /XXX/oracle/app/client/lib/libsqora.so`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I am missing gcc in the server to build, right now I have got only libgcc, meanwhile I try to get gcc into the server, is there anything else  that we can do?

Comment: Do find another AIX-computer having gcc (or xlc), where you can create the binary of dltest32. Also search for duplicated libraries like `/usr/lib/libodbcinst.a` and `/opt/freeware/lib/libodbcinst.a`